# Current human behavior as a genetic heritage

Tags: human-biology, evolution, behaviour

People: I have doubts about genetic heritage, but let me explain the context which has shown up this doubt for you: I was debating about sexism and the following question were put on the discussion: What kind of behavior, most of them come from men, is cultural and social, and what is a genetical heritage from our ancestry? Because I have a feeling that plenty of these behaviors that can be considered, maybe not correct, but at least justifiable. If you have some literature about this subject I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is the subject of an entire field - evolutionary psychology http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_psychologist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [phenotypic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenotype) traits have some part of the variance which is explained by the environment and  some part that is explained by the genes. The heritability is then defined as:

$$H_N = \frac{V_{genetic}}{V_{phenotype}} = \frac{V_{genetic}}{V_{genetic}+V_{environment}+V_{interaction. gene.environment}}$$

where $V_{genetic}$ is the Variance in phenotypic traits due to genes, $V_{phenotype}$ is the total phenotypic variance, $V_{environment}$ is the variance due to environment and $V_{interaction. gene.environment}$ is the variance due to interaction between genes and environment.

So your question (if I understand it correctly) should rather be a list of phenotypic traits (behavior) and ask what is the heritability of each trait in the world-wide human population (or on a given subset of the human population).

I think, there is no objective manner of defining a given phenotypic trait. You should chose subjectively, some behavior, define it accurately and then ask the question what is it's heritability.

Moreover, it is quite hard to measure a behavior. It is much easier to estimate the heritability of height in humans.

There are several different methods in order to estimate heritability of a trait. See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritability#Estimation_methods)

Some of these experiments are not feasible on humans for ethical reasons. Some others are quite limited and are quite expensive. I don't think we have many studies that quantify the heritability of behavioral traits in humans but I might be mistaken.

As said by @AlanBoyd, there is a field called evolutionary psychology that deal with this kind of question. To my knowledge this field is mostly a purely theoretical field and therefore, it does not quite allow to measure heritability.

A good start into this science would be the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_psychology) which seems quite complete.  I can give you some books but I haven't read most of them. [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107622735) and [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405191228) are introductory books in the field. I think [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00486U8N6) is a classic in the field. I read [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465085970) and it is quite interesting. There are actually many books in this field. The best think you can do is maybe to typewrite "evolutionary psychology" in amazon.

As a sidenote: If you enter in the field of evolutionary psychology you might as well be interested by memetic evolution (evolution of culture). [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00814M2BW) is a classic book on the subject.

Be careful in these fields, I think that some ideas do not deserve to be considered as part of science while other do!

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot. Those articles and books that you recommended will be a good start. As i'm not from the biological field of science, so these kind of subjects makes me a little bit confused. I'd ask more especifc questions, but i'll read those material first, maybe it will clear some things to me. Thank you again, guys.